# how to set the character between data set while reading PDF using C# iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

When read PDF using C# iTextSharp, it use white space between data set by default.

This causes me trouble when I try to split by white space, because the data in the PDF contains white space.

For Example, I have a PDF like below, it has a table:

Fund AA|Fixed Income

Fund BB|cash

The result extracted by iTextSharp is:

Fund AA Fixed Income

Fund BB Cash

In that way I was not able to split.
So I want to set a special char, like + between data set. In this way, I can split and judge.

The expected result is:

Fund AA+Fixed Income

Fund BB+Cash

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly do you expect iTextSharp to recognize your "data sets" in the PDF? Hint: PDFs in general have no notion of data sets, merely text and vector graphics and bitmaps drawn somewhere on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no way to set separator from white space to '+' unless we update the source code.

That's how I fix it for me. I download the source code and update it, then get the new itextsharp.dll, which uses '+' as separator now.

I think if we make this a property field or an argument and user can set its value, it is much better.

The lines I update pasted below:
https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs
line 193
https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/SimpleTextExtractionStrategy.cs
line 145

Comment: If I were you, I would not hard-code that replacement in your itextsharp.dll. Even if it works as desired for your current document, there are many documents around for which your change replaces each and every space in the extracted text.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie That been said, it indeed might be a good idea to make the character used for implied gaps configurable via some public setter - there are situations in which a program may want to be able to differentiate  between space characters actually extracted from the content and space characters derived from gaps.